# vis js timeline rolling mode option example not working

Tags: javascript, vis.js

So I'm trying to learn vis js and there's this example about timeline rolling mode option. The code is as is in the example file and i haven't edited it but it seems to only output the html part as there is no timeline that appears and i have no idea if that's what it's suppose to do.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Timeline | rolling mode Option</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="../../../dist/vis.js"></script>
 <link href="../../../dist/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>

<body>

<h1><i id="icon">&#9974;</i>Timeline rolling mode option</h1>

<div id="mytimeline"></div>


<script>
  var container = document.getElementById('mytimeline');

  var items = new vis.DataSet();

  for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) { 
    items.add({
        id: i,
        content: "item " + i,
        start: new Date(new Date().getTime() + i*100000)
    });
  }

  // Configuration for the Timeline
  // specify options
  var options = {
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000000),
    rollingMode: {
      follow: true,
      offset: 0.5
    }
  };

  // create a Timeline
  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
  console.log(items);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the output when I run it.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFshz.png)

Answer (score 1):

As of the time of this writing (v4.21.0), this is an open bug in the GitHub issues list (https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3616).

There is a workaround if you explicitly set the 'rtl' option to false.

```
var options = {
    rollingMode: {
        follow:true,
        offset:0.5
    },
    rtl:false
};
```

I have no idea why the workaround works, but it did for the version I mentioned above (v4.21.0).

Answer (score 0):

It works, but the visibility property of component set to "hidden" by some part of script. You can see it, if you disable this property in  DevTools [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOeaM.png)

Comment: It wont work when you try to scroll or zoom the timeline.